# How to use module from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages in appengine app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Let me start by saying I don't think this actually can work, however, I want to be sure before I abandon my effort to pull in this library.  So I used easy_install to add an API library I found on Github.  I was hoping to use this in my appengine app.  I wrote a simple test handler that would make an instance of the module's main class and print a request.  My dev_appserver will start but won't load the MainPage.  **Any** advice is appreciated!

The error is:

```
ERROR    2013-06-21 04:24:00,450 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devin/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/devin/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in     _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/devin/Projects/appengine/hackTheMidwest/perfectpet4me.py", line 4, in <module>
    import petfinder
ImportError: No module named petfinder
INFO     2013-06-21 04:24:00,455 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And here's the code for my main file:

```
import os
import urllib

import petfinder # THE INSTALLED LIBRARY

from google.appengine.api import users

import jinja2
import webapp2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

class TestPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        # Instantiate the client with your credentials.
        api = petfinder.PetFinderClient(api_key='#####', api_secret='#####')
        pet = api.pet_getrandom()
        self.response.write(pet['name'])


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/test', TestPage),
], debug=True)
```

And my app.yaml:

```
application: ASDFASDFASDF
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

- url: /.*
  script: perfectpet4me.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact purpose of the gaenv tool I built for google app engine.
Here is a blog post for more details:
http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/06/google-app-engine-virtualenv-tool-that.html

But here is the summary:
you install it:

```
pip install gaenv
cd /to/your/project
gaenv
```

Make sure you have your thirdparty package into the requirements.txt and installed and it will create a symlink so it will be uploaded with it since appengine appcfg follows symlinks.

You can also read the code on github on how everything works:
https://github.com/faisalraja/gaenv

Comment: Nice tool! I found out there were other reasons I was not going to be able to use the library I wanted, but this would surely be helpful to others that might stumble on this question.

Comment: yeah there are a lot of packages that probably won't be compatible with google app engine, I could probably come up with some sort of lookup in package source to check weather it used things that aren't compatible with appengine and just give out warning.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Include your third party library in the application's directory and use it in the application. It will be uploaded along with your application when deployed in app engine.